# Application job submission with out duplication

Tags: apache-spark, datastax

We are using DataStax Spark 6.0. 
We are submitting jobs using crontab to run every 5 mins. We wrote script to find if it is running to avoid duplicate submission of same application. Is there a way to stop job submission or keep job in Queue in Spark level, to avoid duplicate jobs with same application.

Thanks 
Rakesh

I tried using Crontab only

Answer (score 0):

You can use oozie to shedule your spark job .

Comment: Hi We are using DataStax. We cant use oozie. My question is can we use something with in Spark?